# why is my php script uploading blank files which should be images

Tags: php, file, types, upload, mime

I am using a php script that I got straight out of a book, no errors. It should work... When I upload a jpg file with my php form the file goes to my uploads folder but it has no type, it is a blank file. When I look at the properties of the file, it just says file. The php script in I am using doesn't use mime types to identify which type of file is being uploaded. But no other students from this course seem to have this problem according to the forums. Could it be windows 8? the permissions on my uploads folder seem fine. any ideas?

here is the code..

```
<?php # Script 19.2 - add_print.php
// This page allows the administrator to add a print (product).

require ('../mysqli_connect.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // Handle the form.

    // Validate the incoming data...
    $errors = array();

    // Check for a print name:
    if (!empty($_POST['print_name'])) {
        $pn = trim($_POST['print_name']);
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter the print\'s name!';
    }

    // Check for an image:
    if (is_uploaded_file ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])) {

        // Create a temporary file name:
        $temp = '../../uploads/' . md5($_FILES['image']['name']);

        // Move the file over:
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $temp)) {

            echo '<p>The file has been uploaded!</p>';

            // Set the $i variable to the image's name:
            $i = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        } else { // Couldn't move the file over.
            $errors[] = 'The file could not be moved.';
            $temp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        }

    } else { // No uploaded file.
        $errors[] = 'No file was uploaded.';
        $temp = NULL;
    }

    // Check for a size (not required):
    $s = (!empty($_POST['size'])) ? trim($_POST['size']) : NULL;

    // Check for a price:
    if (is_numeric($_POST['price']) && ($_POST['price'] > 0)) {
        $p = (float) $_POST['price'];
    } else {
        $errors[] = 'Please enter the print\'s price!';
    }

    // Check for a description (not required):
    $d = (!empty($_POST['description'])) ? trim($_POST['description']) : NULL;

    // Validate the artist...
    if ( isset($_POST['artist']) && filter_var($_POST['artist'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1))  ) {
        $a = $_POST['artist'];
    } else { // No artist selected.
        $errors[] = 'Please select the print\'s artist!';
    }

    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything's OK.

        // Add the print to the database:
        $q = 'INSERT INTO prints (artist_id, print_name, price, size, description, image_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $q);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'isdsss', $a, $pn, $p, $s, $d, $i);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        // Check the results...
        if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt) == 1) {

            // Print a message:
            echo '<p>The print has been added.</p>';

            // Rename the image:
            $id = mysqli_stmt_insert_id($stmt); // Get the print ID.
            rename ($temp, "../../uploads/$id");

            // Clear $_POST:
            $_POST = array();

        } else { // Error!
            echo '<p style="font-weight: bold; color: #C00">Your submission could not be processed due to a system error.</p>'; 
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    } // End of $errors IF.

    // Delete the uploaded file if it still exists:
    if ( isset($temp) && file_exists ($temp) && is_file($temp) ) {
        unlink ($temp);
    }

} // End of the submission IF.

// Check for any errors and print them:
if ( !empty($errors) && is_array($errors) ) {
    echo '<h1>Error!</h1>
    <p style="font-weight: bold; color: #C00">The following error(s) occurred:<br />';
    foreach ($errors as $msg) {
        echo " - $msg<br />\n";
    }
    echo 'Please reselect the print image and try again.</p>';
}

// Display the form...
?>
<h1>Add a Print</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="add_print.php" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="524288" />

    <fieldset><legend>Fill out the form to add a print to the catalog:</legend>

    <p><b>Print Name:</b> <input type="text" name="print_name" size="30" maxlength="60" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['print_name'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['print_name']); ?>" /></p>

    <p><b>Image:</b> <input type="file" name="image" /></p>

    <p><b>Artist:</b> 
    <select name="artist"><option>Select One</option>
    <?php // Retrieve all the artists and add to the pull-down menu.
    $q = "SELECT artist_id, CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, middle_name, last_name) FROM artists ORDER BY last_name, first_name ASC";        
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
            echo "<option value=\"$row[0]\"";
            // Check for stickyness:
            if (isset($_POST['artist']) && ($_POST['artist'] == $row[0]) ) echo ' selected="selected"';
            echo ">$row[1]</option>\n";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<option>Please add a new artist first.</option>';
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc); // Close the database connection.
    ?>
    </select></p>

    <p><b>Price:</b> <input type="text" name="price" size="10" maxlength="10" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['price'])) echo $_POST['price']; ?>" /> <small>Do not include the dollar sign or commas.</small></p>

    <p><b>Size:</b> <input type="text" name="size" size="30" maxlength="60" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['size'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['size']); ?>" /> (optional)</p>

    <p><b>Description:</b> <textarea name="description" cols="40" rows="5"><?php if (isset($_POST['description'])) echo $_POST['description']; ?></textarea> (optional)</p>

    </fieldset>

    <div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></div>

</form>
```

Comment: code? errors? anything?

Comment: just because its in a book does not mean its right, please share the code.

Comment: Did you abandon this thread @user3286022 ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the file extension in the filepath. One way of getting this would be:

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = $path_parts['extension'];
```

and then you would just need to change this line of your code:

```
rename ($temp, "../../uploads/$id");
```

to:

```
rename ($temp, "../../uploads/$id.".".$extension");
```

If your planning on accepting multiple image formats, it's always worthwhile storing it's file extension with it in the database. That way, it only takes a short function to generate the file names, while still keeping the flexibility of integer id's for searching/linking to other databases